# Behaviour of delete in C++ vs. free in C

Tags: c++, pointers

How come in C99 you can free a void pointer, whereas in C++98 you cannot delete a void pointer. Moreover, how come the behaviour is classified as undefined? Depending on the implementation of new, information is stored with the pointer and thus the deallocator should have enough information to deallocate that block. From the C++ standard:

> This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type
>   void * because there are no objects of type void

The only *important* distinction I see is that if you delete a void pointer the destructor will not be ran; resulting in a possible memory leak. But surely this should not warrant undefined behaviour, rather a 'PAY ATTENTION' sign. Is it not similar to the scenario: (pure) virtual destructors for polymorphic destruction. By that I mean, both scenarios require implementation-specific knowledge for deallocating properly.

Comment: An operation can be specified to result in *undefined behavior* even if a compiler can implement well defined behavior. This is a degree of freedom the standard grants to implementers. You are making assumptions about how `new` is usually implemented. Again, an implementer is free to choose a different scheme altogether.

Comment: "PAY ATTENTION" You mean, as in "pay attention, you may destroy the universe by pressing this button"?

Comment: In C++ pointers point to types that may or may not have destructors. void defines nothing. Not type, no size, no destructor. So you can't delete it. You can't also create a void pointer with new. Implementation is not required to store information in allocated blocks, and there is no "memory block" in C++ standard. Because it is not required to have a feature, implementation may or may not have it. Because it may or may not have the feature, it is only safe to assume that implementation does not have the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Depending on the implementation of new" - there's your problem. You're assuming the memory block has some kind of attribute associated with it, but that doesn't have to be the case in C++. The type of the pointer has enough information (namely the size of the class/structure) to free it without any additional information. Also as you said, it's necessary to call the destructor.

Comment: The necessity to call a destructor is not a very convincing point. After all, POD's in C++ do not provide a destructor, or a trivial destructor if you wish. The same *could* be implemented for a `void*`.

Comment: @IInspectable: "Let's delete void without calling destructors" sounds like "let's throw all the good about C++ out of the window for absolutely no reason" to me. Such feature would definitely be abused by newbies who would produce a flood of identical questions. Do you want that?

Comment: @SigTerm The question isn't "what features would make the language safer". It is "why is it specified as resulting in undefined behavior". I'm not promoting a feature that isn't.

Comment: It's specified as resulting in undefined behavior because defining a behavior would limit the options available to the compiler implementers, and the C++ designers did not wish to do that.